# parse data fetch from html

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get some data from the federal reserve and paste into my spreadsheet.

So here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/TWEXMANL.txt");
a=response.getContentText();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var InputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5"); 
InputSheet.getRange("E5:E5").setValue(a); 
}
```

This code pastes all of the output into E5. I just want the data following the "Date" and "Value" pasted into 2 columns.

Can anybody help me with this? I'm sure it's pretty simple for you guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little string manipulation, this becomes very easy:

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/TWEXMANL.txt");
  a=response.getContentText();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var InputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

  //Slice off the text above the columns
  var allData = a.slice(a.indexOf("DATE         VALUE"));

  //Trim spaces between date and value to just 1 space for splitting
  allData = allData.replace(/ +/g, " ");

  //Split the text so each line is a row
  var splitData = allData.split("\n");

  //For some reason, there is an extra line, so remove it
  splitData.pop();

  //Split each row so data is one column and value is another
  for(var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i += 1) {
    splitData[i] = splitData[i].split(" ");
  }

  //Save to spreadsheet. +4 because you start at E5. Note the change to F on the right.
  InputSheet.getRange("E5:F" + (splitData.length + 4)).setValues(splitData);
}
```

I start by taking off the little intro text. I then split the string into an array containing the rows of data. I split each row (a string) into an array as well. This gives me a array I can use `setValues()` on at the bottom. Because this isn't just one cell, I have to specific the exact width and height or it fails.

If you'd like to see the data at any point in there, I recommend `Logger.log(splitData);`

Comment: Oh, and if you don't want the Date/Value row because you have your own headers, add `splitData = splitData.slice(1)` before or after the pop. This will remove the first row.

Comment: Hi Fredric. I have one more question. I'm doing thing else now that does not require paste into spreadsheet, but I need to split the array further. I was thinking of something like a = splitData[i].split(" ").split(",") but that doesn't work. I want to be able to address each element like splitData[0][3]. Right now that only gives me the 4th character of the first element

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is the first `split` returns an array, and the second `split` tries to split that. If you replace all the " " with "," you can then split by "," for the result you want. `.replace(/ /g,",").split(",")` will replace all spaces with commas and then split by commas.