# Nested array manipulation to look like a matrix

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm retrieving some data and the data looks like this:

```
1,  2,  3,  4,  5
6,  7,  8,  9,  10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

I want it to look like this

```
[
   [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]],
   [[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]],
   [[11],[12],[13],[14],[15]]
]
```

So that I may address the array like a matrix, `data[0][1]` would be "2".

Through this answer, it's almost [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173667/parse-data-fetch-from-html), but not quite. I'm having trouble getting to look like what I want.

Comment: "Almost there" means you have some code. Show it!

Comment: it's in that link "there". i didn't want to flood the page.

Comment: Ok, so you leave the coding to SO, it seems ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this, assuming this accurately represents your input data:

```
var data   = "1,2,3,4,5\n6,7,8,9,10\n11,12,13,14,15";
var matrix = data.split('\n').map(function(val) {
  return val.split(',');
});
```

Note that your specified output is probably not what you meant. Each number should probably not be its own single-item array. Instead, the code above produces:

```
[
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[11, 12, 13, 14, 1]
]
```

Which means `matrix[0][1]` would return `2`, as opposed to having to do `matrix[0][1][0]`

Edit: As noted in the comments, I've left it up to you to ensure this fits your browser-support needs. This also goes for every other line of JS you ever write...

Comment: Just note it looks like Array.map is only [supported in IE 9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @EricFreese good note. This needs a shim if IE8 is to be supported (note that jQuery drops IE8 support in 2.0)

Comment: Also, it would be nice to cast all entries to numbers

Comment: Seems to me that would be making assumptions about the poster's requirements/spec

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** - If you need to iterate through an **array** use a simple `for`, and not a `for..in`

- `for..in` returns the items in no guaranteed order which is probably not what you want when working with an array
- `for..in` returns not the just the array elements, but anything added to the Array prototype (meaning if you use a traditional for loop you can be completely confident the code will work regardless of what external libraries may be included on the page. No need to worry that some other coder has added properties/methods to Array.prototype)

---

If `\n` is the line separator and `,` is the item seperator within a line, you can use something like:

```
/* assuming data is already filled like:
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
*/
var arr = data.split("\n"), arr2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != '') arr2.push(arr[i].split(','));
}
console.log(arr2);
/* arr2 will be like:
[
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
]
*/
```

Comment: @JanDvorak - Why? I mean whats the exact disadvantage other than the fact that `for..in` works with named properties as well.

Comment: @the fact that `for..in` grabs named properties as well is a pretty big disadvantage here. I assume your average shimmed `map` function _won't_ have a `split` method.

Comment: Also, `for in` may reorder the properties in any way it seems fit.

Comment: If you use a traditional `for` loop you can be completely confident the code will work regardless of what external libraries may be included on the page. (No need to worry that some other coder has added properties/methods to `Array.prototype`.)

Comment: `for ... in` is not intended to use on Arrays.

Comment: The second point is a definite disadvantage agreed. But the first should be ok in this case since the array object is built specifically for this purpose (assumedly) and is unlikely to contain any other properties. In any case, yes if its a plain array, map is the better.

Comment: @techfoobar any methods added to `Array.prototype` will appear in the enumeration. This practically guarantees the code will mysteriously fail in IE8 and IE8 only.

Comment: @techfoobar I'm prepared to summon a squad of downvoters if your answer gets a robo-upvote.

Comment: Sheesh no, i do this for fun & intellectual entertainment mate, not for petty upvotes, clarifying just in case.. Summon anyone and do whatever you need to, makes no difference to me.. :-)

Comment: robo-upvote = upvote from a person that upvotes anything in the low-quality queue. I am willing to ensure that `for i in array` won't be taken seriously by anyone. And I _hate_ downvoting when my reputation ends with a zero or with the tens digit.

Comment: Point taken. Spreading incorrect information is not my motive either. Still its not about votes for me, it about enlightenment. Today i learned some, thanks to you & others in the comment chain. Will point it out in the answer so it'll be useful for people passing by.

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15'.split(',');
var matrixData = [];
while (data.length > 0) {
    matrixData.push(data.splice(0, 5));
}
document.write(matrixData[0][1]);
```

**Edit:** If you get the data as a simple array of numbers

Comment: Nice, but the input doesn't look like this.